# What does vertical bar | mean in php documentation?

Tags: php, function, htmlspecialchars, code-documentation

The php docs page on [`htmlspecialchars`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)  mentions:

> The default is ENT_QUOTES | ENT_SUBSTITUTE | ENT_HTML401.

My knowledge of `|` in programming documentations is only this [MDN explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Value_definition_syntax#single_bar) of its use in css docs. This seems to be not applicable in php documentation, as `$flags` can be left blank in `htmlspecialchars()`.

In php `htmlspecialchars`, I noticed that, without mentioning the flag, it does not convert single quotes into `&#039`. This certainly implies, `ENT_QUOTES` is not the default value.

So, what does `|` mean in php documentation, and what is the default value of `$flags` in `htmlspecialchars`?

Comment: Its an OR of course

Comment: @NicoHaase It does partially, however, I don't know the inbuilt values of these flags. What is the value of `ENT_QUOTES` - 0,1 or 101? And what would be the resultant of `ENT_QUOTES | ENT_SUBSTITUTE | ENT_HTML401` in empty `htmlspecialchars($str)`? And in `htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_COMPAT,'ISO-8859-1', true);` would the other two defaults are already present?

Comment: Why do you care about the values of the single constants? Why not dump them, each single one, to check which value they contain? Also, please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: @NicoHaase This is new info to me to grasp. But my original question is still valid, _The default is ENT_QUOTES | ENT_SUBSTITUTE | ENT_HTML401_ -- what does this mean? Give me some time to add more details, I need to read the linked post first.

Comment: So, what's your question then? What do you mean by "as $flags can be left blank"? That's basic PHP stuff to have default values for optional arguments

Comment: @NicoHaase Consider [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position#formal_syntax) example of css documentation. In css you cannot have `.someclass { backgound-poistion: ;}` -- you can't leave the value empty. `|` in css docs  mean `OR` with at least one value being mentioned, but in php you can call `htmlspecialchars()` without mentioning any flag.

Comment: @user31782 I would suggest not trying to compare procedural languages like PHP and JS against specialist languages like CSS. Trying to draw parallels between them is just going to get you more confused. Instead, have a look for some introductory PHP tutorials if you're not familiar; or browse the PHP manual - for instance, [default function arguments are discussed in this section](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default). (The mention of "C++-style" is not particularly helpful, but the rest of the section is hopefully helpful.)

Answer (score 3):

It is a [bitwise OR](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php).

It combines a set of options (internally expressed as numbers) into a single value that means "All of these options combined".

---

Let's look at how that works.

Consider that you might have flags:

```
FLAG_A = 1
FLAG_B = 2
FLAG_C = 4
```

In binary that would be

```
FLAG_A = 001
FLAG_B = 010
FLAG_C = 100
```

So if you had

```
FLAG_A | FLAG_C
```

You'd get `101` and that could be compared successfully to FLAG_A or FLAG_C.

In decimal it is represented as 5, but the point of flags like these is to store a combination of yes/no options in a compact form.

Here's a practical example in JS (this kind of bitwise logic is foundational to computer programming so works the same in most languages).

```js
const FLAG_A = 0b001;
const FLAG_B = 0b010;
const FLAG_C = 0b100;

const ACTIVE_FLAGS = FLAG_A | FLAG_C;

console.log(Boolean(FLAG_A & ACTIVE_FLAGS));
console.log(Boolean(FLAG_B & ACTIVE_FLAGS));
console.log(Boolean(FLAG_C & ACTIVE_FLAGS));
```

---

Re your comment

> however, I don't know the inbuilt values of these flags. What is the value of ENT_QUOTES - 0,1 or 101? And what would be the resultant of ENT_QUOTES | ENT_SUBSTITUTE | ENT_HTML401 in empty htmlspecialchars($str)?

The actual values don't matter. You can consider them internal to PHP. You only need to worry about the constants.

`ENT_QUOTES | ENT_SUBSTITUTE | ENT_HTML401` is the default, so those three options are all turned on.

The documentation tells you that `ENT_QUOTES` means "Will convert both double and single quotes..". So you know that that is how the function will work by default. (Along with whatever it says about the other two options that are turned on).

> And in htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_COMPAT,'ISO-8859-1', true); would the other two defaults are already present?

No. If you pass a different set of values for the options, you change the defaults.

If you say `ENT_COMPAT` then that turns `ENT_COMPAT` on and *everything else* off.

Comment: *ENT_QUOTES | ENT_SUBSTITUTE | ENT_HTML401 is the default, so those three options are all turned on.* -- No, `ENT_QUOTES` is not turned on by default.

Comment: @user31782 — The [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) disagrees with you.

Comment: I have a running example of it. Thats why I got down the rabbit hole of this topic. I have `href` getting dynamic string with mysqli-php through `htmlspecialchars` and it doesn't convert single quotes to html entities. Try: `$str = "'";    
    var_dump(htmlspecialchars($str, ENT_QUOTES));` and `$str = "'";    
    var_dump(htmlspecialchars($str));` You get different results.

Comment: @user31782 — You're running an out of date version of PHP. The documentation says it was changed to include `ENT_QUOTES` in version 8.1.